# CartoDB, add logo

Tags: carto

I am trying to add my own logo to my CartDB map. I have already removed CartoDBs own logo. Can I use the editor to add my own logo or do I have to use cartodb.js?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8"> </meta>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v2/themes/css/cartodb.ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<style>
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#cartodb-map { width: 100%; height:100%; background: black; z-index:1;}
#logo {width: 7%; height: 4%; position: absolute; bottom: 1%; left: 1%; z-index:2147483647; opacity: 0.75;}
</style>

<!-- fullscreen button-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.css" />
<script src="lib/fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.js"></script

<!-- logo-->
<img id="logo" src="img/imm_infinto.png" alt="Logo"/>

</head>

<body>

// initiate leaflet map
var map = new L.Map('cartodb-map', { 
    center: [51,9],
    zoom: 4,
    minZoom:3,
    maxZoom: 16,
});

//load basemap
var OSM= new L.tileLayer('http://a{s}.acetate.geoiq.com/tiles/acetate-hillshading/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'}).addTo(map);

//load data from CartoDB
var layerUrl= 'http://intermodalmap.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/0931f4e4-76f8-11e4-b51ea90d/viz.json';

//load satellit map
var Esri_WorldImagery = new L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community' });

  cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
    .addTo(map)
    .on('done', function() {
    }).on('error', function() {
    });
    };

L.control.fullscreen({
    position: 'topleft', // change the position of the button can be topleft, topright, bottomright or bottomleft, defaut topleft
    title: 'Open fullscreen', // change the title of the button, default Full Screen
    titleCancel: 'Exit fullscreen mode', // change the title of the button when fullscreen is on, default Exit Full Screen
    content: null, // change the content of the button, can be HTML, default null
    forceSeparateButton: true
}).addTo(map);

// events are fired when entering or exiting fullscreen.
map.on('enterFullscreen', function(){
    console.log('entered fullscreen');
});

map.on('exitFullscreen', function(){
    console.log('exited fullscreen');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your logo as an overlay image element inside the CartoDB Editor, you can find more info here: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor.html#add-element

You could also do it by using CartoDB.js and including an image on top of the map element by using HTML.

Comment: I know its a while ago that I asked this question. I have added my logo to my map which worked quite well with css. But I just realised that it disapears when I open the fullscreen. Do I need to add it somehow to my fullscreen function? I will add a short version of my code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty positive you can do it in the editor by adding an image, but i know for a fact it can be done in the css or in cartodb.js  just google adding a custom image to cartodb and more than a few pages will pop up.